# deselect the selected row on grid refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that displays policies. each policy has more than 1 plan,also I have a button that searches the policies. Now I select 2 plans for a particular policy and search other policy,but when I search the previous policy(the 1 for which I have selected plans) the plans I have selected retain.

How do I deselect them whenever the grid reloads??

I have tried this ,but it did not work

```
jQuery("#tblAgencyList").jqGrid('GridUnload');
```

Comment: Was your question answered?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
// Reset your row selection
$("#tblAgencyList").jqGrid('resetSelection');

// Reload the grid
$("#tblAgencyList").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that you have nothing selected you can build into the loadComplete, so it will fire after your grid is loaded.

```
loadComplete: function () {
    $(this).jqGrid('resetSelection');
    ...
}
```

but simply reloading the grid should deselect any selected items.  You can always load a grid to the page it was on by the following:

```
$('#gridName').trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: $('#gridName').getGridParam('page')}]);
```